# Transaction-per-request and Jersey

Tags: transactions, jersey

I'd like to implement transaction-per-request in conjunction with Jersey resources.  By that, I just mean I want a single place to manage transactions, something like:

```
try {
  chain.doFilter(request, response);
  commitSession();
} finally {
  rollbackSession(); // no-op if already committed
  closeSession();
}
```

In the past, I've done similar things with Servlet Filters, but that won't work in Jersey.  In Jersey , the exception is intercepted and converted into a 500 long before web container Filters regain control.  I suppose I could stick w/ the Filter approach, and check response codes, but that's not very appealing.  I've seen a [couple](http://markmail.org/search/?q=jersey+transaction+Closeable#query:jersey%20transaction%20Closeable%20list%3Anet.java.dev.jersey.users+page:1+mid:aefgmci6r2thkqxc+state:results) [conversations](http://markmail.org/message/rk6wduyoln7kkj34?q=jersey+ResourceFilter+transaction+Closeable#query:jersey%20ResourceFilter%20transaction%20Closeable+page:1+mid:pvsawfqmhvqtubmk+state:results) about this, but I've been unable to come up with a solid approach using ResourceFilter, CloseableService, or ServletContainer, etc.  My terrible solution so far has been to do implement a custom ExceptionMapper and perform a rollback there.  Has anyone solved this cleanly?

Disclaimer - this project currently doesn't use Spring, so I'd rather avoid it for this small use case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No Jersey love, eh?

http://markmail.org/thread/orcctyu7hczx3d5w

Comment: I read through the mail conversation. As it is from 2010, it does not cover Jersey 2, but thought I should just ask here if you still use the same logic for dealing with transactions? I was also wondering what happens in the ContainerResponseFilter if an exception is thrown (for example, if transaction.commit() fails)?

Comment: Sorry... I haven't worked in Jersey or this project since 2010 :(